# Inserting a value into the table with a condition

Tags: mysql

I created a table  with the attributes id,name,email. Now I want to insert a value only when the occurrence of name is less than 3, i.e. name<3. As cannot use where clause in insert statement, is there any other way to do that?

I used group by to know the occurrence of a given value. Now, i am stuck. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the result of a `SELECT` query, and it can use a `WHERE` clause.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (name, email)
SELECT 'newName', 'newEmail'
FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable
    WHERE name = 'newName'
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
```

`DUAL` is a dummy table that can be used in queries that are generating data dynamically.